# Multiple commands on one line in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to execute multiple statements on one line in SQL Server 2005. How do I do the following on a single line:

```
use master
go
sp_spaceused mytable
```

When I try `use master; go; sp_spaceused mytable` I get `Incorrect syntax near 'go'`.

When I try `use master go sp_spaceused mytable` I get `Incorrect syntax near 'go'`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
use master; sp_spaceused mytable;
```

should suffice. `GO` simply [signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: I discovered that in addition to using the semi-colon, and not using `GO`, I also had to use the keyword `EXEC` in front of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need `GO`. Just use `;`

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided thus far are incorrect.  It does not work to combine lines with a semi-colon if the lines must be in a separate batch.  Try this one:

```
DECLARE @x int; DECLARE @x int;
```

Comment: That's a good point / worthwhile comment... (not an 'answer' per se)